# Unpacking inner tarball failed: invalid argument

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

When I try to get the dependencies (mix deps.get) I´m receiving this error:

- Updating ecto (Hex package)
  Checking package (https://repo.hex.pm/tarballs/ecto-2.2.7.tar)
  Fetched package
  ** (Mix) Unpacking inner tarball failed: invalid argument

I´m using Windows 10.

Comment: The tar file at that URL looks valid to me. Have you tried running the command a couple of times more? Looks like the download failed for some reason. Do you get a 242176 byte file if you open that URL in your browser?

Comment: It looks like a bug in hex. There is another guy with the same problem.

Comment: I would suggest running any *nix-based OS for the Elixir development. One might even opt-in for [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) with any Linux-based OS inside. I doubt anybody from both elixir/erlang core teams use Windows and ports to it _might_ suffer (though everybody puts the best effort to make such things happen as rare as possible.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Windows for Elixir development.  There are some hoops to jump through to ensure that dependencies compile in some cases, especially some of the crypto libraries (comeonein, for example, needs a C compiler and appropriate runtime flags set for build).  Mix and ecto are definitely working.  Have you installed hex locally?

Comment: Did anyone solve this isdue, i am trying with latest version of elixir, otp etc, same isdue when trying to install phoenix on barebones windows, dont want to use virtual environments.

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue, i am trying with latest version of elixir, otp etc, same issue when trying to install phoenix, stops at ecto with innermost tarball error on barebones windows, have installed all in c drive and running command window as administrator!, don't want to use virtual environments. Any good links to solving this isuue on window's in 2022

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using WSL for Windows 10

You have to move your project to a folder inside the WSL environment, i.e.

You have your project inside a directory like this:

```
C:/Users/UserName/Documents/Projects/project-name
```

Move it to a directory like this:

```
/home/user-name
```

Notice that this new directory is part of the WSL environment, just copy it (assuming you're inside the folder where your project is):

```
mv project-name /home/user-name
```